# Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

Can I install Visual Studio 2005 and 2010 on the same computer? Would it cause any problems?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can do so. I have VS 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed on single machine and they all work independently.

However, before doing so, keep in mind that projects made in lower versions can be opened in higher version only once because after that it will be upgraded to higher version but the opposite is not possible, i.e. backward compatibility is possible but forward compatibility is not possible.

Comment: Interestingly, though, VS '11 can read *and write* VS 2010 solutions. So no upgrade wizard is required there, and backward compatibility is maintained.

Comment: I had already VS2013(Ultimate) but when i installed unity3D, it automatically installed VS2015(community). So i thought, if i have VS2015 community version, i can use it to develop Xamarin Apps.So do so , i updated VS2015 to get some missing packages for it. But now it started to update both versions at once, will it cause an error? @RyanO'Hara

Comment: @JokerFan Try it and find out.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do that, no problem. I personally have VB Express 2005, VS 2008, VB Express 2010, C# Express 2010, Visual Web Developer Express 2010, and VS 2011 all going at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I have Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on the same machine, with no problems.  2005 would be the same; they are isolated from each other.

Comment: I had already VS2013(Ultimate) but when i installed unity3D, it automatically installed VS2015(community). So i thought, if i have VS2015 community version, i can use it to develop Xamarin Apps.So do so , i updated VS2015 to get some missing packages for it. But now it started to update both versions at once, will it cause an error?