# Is it possible to install two different versions of Visual Studio in the same computer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible? or there is a compatibility issues between the two versions? Because our company is using an outdated version of visual studio (VS2005) and I wanted to try out Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013 for the purpose of learning while there is no project to do. (any of the three newer version is fine) but I don't know if it'll affect the datas of the currently installed visual studio 2005.

Can I still install a newer version without affecting the older version of visual studio?

Comment: A lot of questions aks this (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251103/can-i-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-on-the-same-computer?rq=1) -> Yes you can. I personally do it ;-)

Comment: Oops. sorry, lol :D Should I delete this thread?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can install multiple versions of Visual studio side by side.But install the lower versions first.

> If you use Visual Studio 2013 to open a solution that was created in Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2010 with Service Pack 1 (SP1), you can later open and modify the solution again in the older version as long as you haven't implemented any features that are specific to Visual Studio 2013.

So take care about backward compatibility.Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Is it mandatory to install the older version first? I unfortunately need to install VS2008 on a machine running VS2013.

Comment: I'm also curious. I need to install 2015 on a system that already has 2019.

Answer (score 5):

You can install all (although I only have experience with VS 6 upwards) Visual Studio Versions side-by-side without problems.

Comment: I had already VS2013(Ultimate) but when i installed unity3D, it automatically installed VS2015(community). So i thought, if i have VS2015 community version, i can use it to develop Xamarin Apps.So do so , i updated VS2015 to get some missing packages for it. But now it started to update both versions at once, will it cause an error?

Answer (score 5):

I have vs2005 2008 and 2012 running with no issue. Just don't open your 2005 projects/solutions in later versions as this will attempt to convert them to later versions which then will be no longer compatible with 2005. Visual studio will give you plenty of warnings if you do this though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. You can install Visual Studio versions side-by-side. However, Microsoft is recommending to install the old version first before you install the later version.

> We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2013 before you install Visual Studio 2015.

You can check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) for further info.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. If you need more details please check [Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) .

Comment: Great help! Thanks for the link ;)