# install visual studio 2013 after visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nopcommerce

I need to instal Visual Studio 2013 after I already have instaled Visual Studio 2010. I develop nopCommerce v2.65 webshop application in Visual Studio 2010 and now I want to make new webshop in nopCommerce v3.5 for which I need at least Visual Studio 2012. I choose VS 2013. 
Now I wonder if I will have some problems if I still continue developing nopcommerce webshop v2.65 in VS 2010 and the new one nopCommerce v3.5 webshop in VS 2013? Will new VS installation overwrite .NET 4 binaries?
Have anyone some experience with that? Have I take something into consideration?
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: All versions of Visual Studio can be installed independently in your system. Installation of VS doesn't affects installed .NET frameworks at all.

Comment: Did you try searching? This has been asked and answered in various forms before,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926702/is-it-possible-to-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-in-the-same-co) and [Is it possible to install two different versions of Visual Studio in the same computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926702/is-it-possible-to-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-in-the-same-co)

Comment: yes I searched various forums before but I was still insecure after reading the answers. thanks for friendliness.

Answer (score 1):

You can target a specific binary by right clicking project and choosing framework. You should be fine with converting to VS 2013

Comment: Thank you ravingheaven. I will not convert the project. I just wonder if new installation don't damage the old one (.net 4.5 not overvrite .net 4 binaries) and that I still can open old project in older version and build and deploy it without problems.