# Visual Studio Community Edition Side by side with Visual Studio Preview

Tags: visual-studio

Is it safe to install Visual Studio 2017 Preview alongside Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition ?
It is mentioned that's it's possible to install both VS and VS Preview but they didn't say anything about the versions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251103/can-i-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: it's not a duplicate of "Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?" because this one asks about a preview version with a normal one

Comment: Thanks @Wassim, I mentioned that in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've flagged this as a [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251103/can-i-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-on-the-same-computer) [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926702/is-it-possible-to-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-in-the-same-co), but I'm not sure if your question relates specifically to the *Preview* edition of Visual Studio, so I'll answer here as well and let a mod decide.  The answer is that there's no difference between this and other side-by-side installations, and many developers keep several versions installed like this, especially if you're evaluating a Preview build.

The installs are separate and they can be installed and uninstalled independently with a few caveats - this is for VS2015, but the same points apply to VS2017 ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx)):

- If you use Visual Studio 2015 to open a solution that was created in Visual Studio 2013, you can later open and modify the solution again in the older version as long as you haven't implemented any features that are specific to Visual Studio 2015.
- If you try to use Visual Studio 2015 to open a solution that was created in Visual Studio 2013 or an earlier version, you might need to modify your projects and files to be compatible with Visual Studio 2015. For more information, see the Port, Migrate, and Upgrade Visual Studio Projects page.
- If you uninstall a version of Visual Studio on a computer that has more than one version installed, the file associations for Visual Studio are removed for all versions. You can remap these file associations by using the Restore File Associations button on the Environment, General page of the Options dialog box.
- Visual Studio doesn't automatically upgrade extensions because not all extensions are compatible. You must reinstall the extensions from the Visual Studio Gallery or the software publisher.