# Can I install VS2013 in a machine with VS2010 ultimate without conflicts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS2010 ultimate in my computer. Now I want to install VS2013 on this machine without affecting the VS2010 so that I can work on both project types. Let me know what steps are to be followed while installing VS2013

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251103/can-i-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of Visual Studio can be installed on the same computer without any problems. Just run the VS2013 setup in your case. See MSDN documentation on side-by-side VS installations here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609(v=vs.120).aspx