# Is it ok to install visual studio 2008 over visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

My system is having VS 2015 and windows 7 Enterprise.

I have some solution file, which was created in vs 2008.

After opening in vs 2008, there are some upgraded log from vs 2015.
a lot of errors needs to be resolved to make build successed.

Is it ok to install visual studio 2008 over visual studio 2015 ?

this link [Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251103/can-i-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-on-the-same-computer) does not tell if it is ok to install lower version over higher version.

Comment: can you specify what errors did you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install two different versions of Visual Studio on the same computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251103/can-i-install-two-different-versions-of-visual-studio-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but with a bit of risk that some features of the newer VS will break. I have no experience with these two combined, but in the past things got broken for me after installing vs2005 after vs2008 or vs2010. A re-install of the newer version would be needed if this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is ok. You can have many different visual studios installed on your machine.